# Difference between 貸す and 貸し出す

Tags: word-choice, usage, synonyms

What is the difference between 貸す and 貸し出す?
Please explain it to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[類語例解辞典 says](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/1828/m0u/)

> **[使い分け]**
>   【１】「貸す」は、一般的に広く用いられる。
>   【２】「貸し出す」は、公共機関や店が、そこの所有物を一時的に、そこから持ち出すことを認める意。また、銀行などの金融機関では金銭についてもいう。

Namely, the difference is that 貸し出す is used when some sort of organization, store, or bank is doing the lending.

(If this is accurate, I don't think 貸す and 貸し出す are parallel to "lend" and "lend out" in English, where I think the only difference is "lend out" is more natural without an indirect object: ○ "He lent out the book last Monday", ? "He lent the book last Monday".)

Comment: I never said "lend out" feels intransitive and I in fact quite disagree with that. Regarding habituality, "lend out" certainly works better because it doesn't require the indirect object and normally one doesn't lend habitually to the same person. But I still see no similarity between it and 貸し出す, as you can still say "I lend out books all the time".

Comment: Somehow I misread that part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning of 貸す is "lend".　"貸し出す" have the image like bringing out the place where the thing is from.  . For example, we don't say "図書館の本は貸し中です。" but say "図書館の本は、貸し出し中です。".